# Does a default constructor always initialize all members?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, initialization, default-constructor

I could swear I don't remember having seen this before, and I'm having trouble believing my eyes:

Does an implicitly-defined default constructor for a non-aggregate class initialize its members or no?

In Visual C++, when I run this innocent-looking code...

```
#include <string>
struct S { int a; std::string b; };
int main() { return S().a; }
```

... to my astonishment, it returns a non-zero value! But if I remove field `b`, then it returns zero.

I've tried this on all versions of VC++ I can get my hands on, and it seems to do this on all of them.

But when I try it on Clang and GCC, the values are initialized to zero, whether I try it in C++98 mode or C++11 mode.

What's the correct behavior? Is it not guaranteed to be zero?

Comment: Specifically _which_ versions of VC++? There is no version with full C++11 support yet so this really matters.

Comment: Fixed in [Visual Studio 2015 Preview](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx). It is another good reason to transfer Windows projects to it (along with `constexpr` and android clang and gdb integration)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoting C++11:

> **5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]**
>
> 2 The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) `void` type, creates a prvalue of the specified type,which is value-initialized (8.5; no initialization is done for the `void()` case). [...]
>
> **8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]**
>
> 7 To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - ...
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if `T`'s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - ...

So in C++11, `S().a` should be zero: the object is zero-initialized before the constructor gets called, and the constructor never changes the value of `a` to anything else.

Prior to C++11, value initialization had a different description. Quoting N1577 (roughly C++03):

> To *value-initialize* an object of type T means:
>
> - ...
> - if `T` is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of `T` is value-initialized;
> - ...
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

Here, value initialization of `S` did not call any constructor, but caused value initialization of its `a` and `b` members. Value initialization of that `a` member, then, caused zero initialization of that specific member. In C++03, the result was also guaranteed to be zero.

Even earlier than that, going to the very first standard, C++98:

> The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* (7.1.5.2) for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) `void` type, creates an rvalue of the specified type, whose value is determined by default-initialization (8.5; no initialization is done for the `void()` case).

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for `T` is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor);
> - ...
> - otherwise, the storage for the object is zero-initialized.

So based on that very first standard, VC++ is correct: when you add a `std::string` member, `S` becomes a non-POD type, and non-POD types don't get zero initialization, they just have their constructor called. The implicitly generated default constructor for `S` does not initialise the `a` member.

So all compilers can be said to be correct, just following different versions of the standard.

As reported by @Columbo in the comments, later versions of VC++ do cause the `a` member to be initialized, in accordance with more recent versions of the C++ standard.

Comment: it would certainly seem that 8.5(10) leads to 8.5(7) and eventually 8.5(5) and since `a` is indeed the first non-static member, I cannot see how it would not be value-initialized. I think you're correct; that zero should be there in the case of `()`. +1. I don't have a 14-std but it would appear 8.5(10) was moved to 8.5(11) if Columbo's cites are accurate.

Comment: Haha, I also thought of providing the same argumentation for C++03 a couple of minutes ago. I didn't steal it, I promise. :D

Comment: @Columbo :) Also added C++98 text, showing that VC++ isn't necessarily wrong, just following an outdated standard.

Comment: @hvd That's absolutely hilarious though, the newest version of VC++ can be expected to follow at least C++03 (which was introduced more than ten years ago). I'd say this requires a bug report.

Comment: @Columbo From what I can find on other answers on SO, it's already been reported many times, but the links to the reports no longer work, so it's hard to tell whether it's since been fixed unless you can actually try the most recent version of their compiler.

Comment: @hvd I think [the asker is using an outdated version](http://rextester.com/SNWE52483) ... ;)

Comment: @Columbo Ah, good to know. Do you want to add that to your answer, or shall I add it to mine?

Comment: @hvd ... let's go crazy and add it to both.

Comment: @Columbo looks like [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/SNWE52483) uses something other than latest stable build of MSVC. Latest release  Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 (and anything older than it) fails `assert`s. Visual Studio 2015 Preview passes.

Comment: Whoa this means this was a mistake in the C++98 version right? Because I think C++03 was meant to correct C++98...

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, pretty much. `T()` was intended to generate the same value as what `static T val; // no initializer` would be initialized to, and wording in the original C++98 standard did not have that effect.

Answer (score 12):

<sub>(All quotes in the first section are from N3337, C++11 FD with editorial changes)</sub>

I cannot reproduce the behavior with the [VC++ on rextester](http://rextester.com/SNWE52483). Presumably the bug (see below) is already fixed in the version they are using, but not in yours - @Drop reports that the latest release, VS 2013 Update 4, fails the assertion - while the VS 2015 preview passes them.

Just to avoid misunderstandings: `S` is indeed an aggregate. [dcl.init.aggr]/1:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

That is irrelevant though.
The semantics of value initialization are important. [dcl.init]/11:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e.,
>   `()`, shall be value-initialized.

[dcl.init]/8:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a
>          default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> - **if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized** and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if `T` has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
> - [..]

Clearly this holds regardless of whether `b` is in `S` or not. So at least in C++11 in both cases `a` should be zero. [Clang and GCC show the correct behavior](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64f2a81f6e0cd49d).

---

And now let's have a look at the C++03 FD:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1) [..]
> - **if `T` is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class
>     component of `T` is value-initialized;**
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized**

That is, even in C++03 (where the above quote in [dcl.init]/11 also exists in /7), `a` should be `0` in both cases.
Again, [both GCC and Clang are correct](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08eab888d8f32c70) with -std=c++03.

As shown in [hvd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27668438/3647361), your version is compliant for C++98, and C++98 only.

Comment: And now reference the actual standard that you're using. There are several to choose from.

Comment: This is missing a very relevant detail: when the `b` field is removed, then `S().a` is zero. Your answer doesn't yet explain what difference the `b` field makes. Or are you saying that's equally undefined, and zero is just as valid a result? (I don't think that's right, and I don't think that's what you're trying to say.)

Comment: @hvd Ahh, I didn't see that it was S()! I'll quickly correct the answer.

Comment: Heh, I had just posted that too, seconds after you edited your answer. :) I'll not delete my answer yet though. I think this is an area in which later standards changed the rules, and if VC++ follows an older standard, its behaviour may still be correct.